# What chemistry lab experiements can I do based on the bicarbonate buffer system?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I want to do a chemistry experiment, based on the reactions present in the bicarbonate buffer system. It needs to be heavily chemistry based, rather than biology based-- any suggestions  preferably based on a factor other than pH for the independent variable (pH can be dependent variable)? Especially preferable if they don’t involve the use of a pH meter, and can be clearly tied to chemical principles. Thanks!